# error: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, random

```
def strategy(board):
    import random
    #t_1 =, t_2 and t_3 are ranges from 0 to a object named board
    t_1 = [board[0] - i for i in range (0,(board[0] + 1))]
    t_2 = [board[1] - i for i in range (0,(board[1] + 1))]
    t_3 = [board[2] - i for i in range (0,(board[2] + 1))]

    #randomly chooses a single number from each range
    x = random.choice (t_1)
    y = random.choice (t_2)
    z = random.choice (t_3)

    #randomly chooses one of those 3 randomly chosen numbers
    q = random.choice (x,y,z)
```

As you can see the code randomly chooses a number from 3 different ranges and assigns each of them to a different variable. Once that is done, it randomly chooses one out of the 3 numbers chosen previously and assigns that a new variable. 
I keep getting the error mentioned in the title. I cant figure out whats wrong.
Thanks for the help
p.s. 
I am using python 3 with PyCharm

Comment: `q = random.choice ([x,y,z])`. Pass a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice` accepts a list as an argument, so it should be:

```
q = random.choice([x,y,z])
```